# Сделать Update двух таблиц

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql

Возник вопрос по обновлению данных в двух таблицах, вот функция

```
public function save($task_id) {

    if ($this->id) {

        $sql = 'update phones set phone=\''.$this->phone.'\', data=\'\', '.
            'reply=\''.$this->reply.'\', duration=\''.$this->duration.'\', status=\''.$this->status.'\' '.
            'where id=\''.$this->id.'\'';
        $result = DB::query(Database::UPDATE, $sql)->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $result = $this->id;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }

    } else {

        $sql = 'insert into phones(task_id, date, phone, data, reply, duration, status) values('.
            '\''.$task_id.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->date.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->phone.'\', '.
            '\'\', '.
            '\''.$this->reply.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->duration.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->status.'\' '.
            ')';
        $result = DB::query(Database::INSERT, $sql)->execute();

        if ($result) {
            list($id, $rows) = $result;
            $this->id = (int)$id;
            $result = $this->id;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    }

    return ($result);
}
```

Необходимо чтобы поля `task_id, data, reply, status` также апдейтились в таблице `billing`. Помогите пожалуйста исправить функцию

Comment: task_id, data, reply, status поля, сорри)

Comment: В MySQL имеется `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. И в PostgreSQL имеется аналогичная конструкция. Так что не надо устраивать эту прыготню с тасканием ненужных данных с сервера и обратно. А для вставки во вторую таблицу ссылки на первую по известным данным используют `INSERT ... SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

Написал функцию

public function save($task_id) {

```
    if ($this->id) {

        $sql = 'update phones set phone=\''.$this->phone.'\', data=\'\', '.
            'reply=\''.$this->reply.'\', duration=\''.$this->duration.'\', status=\''.$this->status.'\' '.
            'where id=\''.$this->id.'\'';

        $sqlbill = 'update billing set data=\'\', '. 'reply=\''.$this->reply.'\', status=\''.$this->status.'\' '.'where dst=\''.$phone'\'';
        $result = DB::query(Database::UPDATE, $sql, $sqlbill)->execute();

        if ($result) {
            $result = $this->id;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }

    } else {

        $sql = 'insert into phones(task_id, date, phone, data, reply, duration, status) values('.
            '\''.$task_id.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->date.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->phone.'\', '.
            '\'\', '.
            '\''.$this->reply.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->duration.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->status.'\' '.
            ')';
        $sqlbill = 'insert into billing(task_id, data, reply, status) values('.
            '\''.$task_id.'\', '.
            '\'\', '.
            '\''.$this->reply.'\', '.
            '\''.$this->status.'\' '.
            ')';
        $result = DB::query(Database::INSERT, $sql, $sqlbill)->execute();

        if ($result) {
            list($id, $rows) = $result;
            $this->id = (int)$id;
            $result = $this->id;
        } else {
            $result = false;
        }
    }

    return ($result);
}
```

Comment: почитайте про START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, ROLLBACK и про конструкцию TRY CATCH